# Font color won't change in ASP-classic site using javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, asp-classic

I've got a table, and as I mouse over this cell, the background and font colors are supposed to change and then change back when i mouseOut, but for some reason, I can't seem to get the font to change color.  I'm using asp-classic and internet explorer 8.

```
<TH <%if boolHighlight=false then %>onMouseOver="this.bgColor='#E3E31B'; this.style.color='#ffffff';" onMouseOut="this.bgColor='#FFFFFF'; this.style.color='#000000';" <%end if%>style="width: 9%; cursor: hand; border-right: none; align: center; vertical-align: center;" 
    title="Click to get info">
    <font color="navy"><%= RS("ROLL_ID")%></font>
</TH>
```

Comment: Font tags are deprecated. Please consider not using them.

Comment: You are not going to be able to change the color of an element when there is an inline style. CSS rules 101

Comment: Okay, thank you very much for the information.  I haven't really had a chance to use much CSS.  I'm a console developer who was thrown into web development, so everything but basic HTML is brand new to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your ASP file

```
<% 
  thClass = IIf(boolHighlight, "hl", "")
%>

<!-- later... -->

<th class="info <%=thClass%>" title="Click to get info"><%=RS("ROLL_ID")%></th>
```

in your CSS file

```
th.info {
  color: navy;
  background-color: white;
}
th.info.hl:hover {
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #E3E31B;
}
```

Notes

- Don't use font tags. Ever.
- Don't use inline styles, use CSS classes and a separate CSS file instead.
- Don't do roll-over effects in JavaScript. CSS `:hover` has been made for that.